# How can I reorder the index positioning of a duplicate/mapped array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a button that has a function called clickNext(). Whenever that button is clicked, it increments the index position (scope.selected) on an array called filteredData.

```
        function clickNext() {
            var length = scope.vm.filteredData.length;

            if (scope.selected === length - 1) {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                scope.selected = (scope.selected + 1) % length;
            }
        }
```

I have mapped out this array to an identical array called xsData. The xsData is exactly like filteredData, except it's sorted differently.

How can I have clickNext function increase the scope.selected incrementer for the xsData array? Right now, the clickNext function still increments in the order of the filteredData array.

I have tried the following:

```
clickNext(){
  var oldXsIndex = filteredToXs(scope.selected);
  scope.selected = oldXsIndex + 1;
} 


function filteredToXs( filteredIndex ) {
  var ccir = scope.vm.filteredData[ filteredIndex ];
  var xsIndex = scope.xsDropdown.findIndex( function(item) {
    return item.trackingNumber === ccir.trackingNumber;
} );
  if( xsIndex >= 0 ) return xsIndex;
  if( xsIndex === -1 ) return 0;  // Default value }
```

I feel as if the solution is similar to above, but it's not incrementing in the way I have tried.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="right-btn col-xs-6" role="menuitem" ng-click="clickNext()" >Next</button>
```

This is how I'm getting the xsData array, and sorting it based on different properties

```
function populateXsDropdown()
        {
            scope.xsData = scope.filteredData
                .map(function (ccir, index)
                {
                    return {
                        index: index,
                        catNum: ccir.catNum,
                        trackingNumber: ccir.trackingNumber,
                        catType: ccir.catType
                    };
                })
                .sort(function (a, b)
                {
                    var left = a.catNum.match(/CAT (I+) #([0-9]+)/);
                    var right = b.catNum.match(/CAT (I+) #([0-9]+)/);
                    if (left[1].length == right[1].length)
                    {
                        return left[2] - right[2];
                    }
                    else return left[1].length - right[1].length;
                });
        }
```

Comment: please share html  and array details to debug easily

Comment: included as much as I can. All relevant info is in there though. I think I'm on the right track with the solution. But currently hitting a wall